# Как можно задать URL главной странице с помощью файла html?

Tags: java, html, url, backend, jetty

Главная страница сайта выводится по запросу http://localhost:8080/index.html, как можно вывести её  с помощью http://localhost:8080/main?

```
public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DBService dbService = new DBService();

        try {
            long userId = dbService.addUser("tully");
            System.out.println("Added user id: " + userId);

            UsersDataSet dataSet = dbService.getUser(userId);
            System.out.println("User data set: " + dataSet);

            dbService.cleanUp();
        } catch (DBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        AccountService  accountService = new AccountService();
        
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);

        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder( new UsersServlet(accountService)), "/main");
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SessionsServlet(accountService)), "/defolt");
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SignInServlet(accountService)), "/signin");
        context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new SignUpServlet(accountService)),"/signup");


        ResourceHandler resource_handler = new ResourceHandler();
        resource_handler.setResourceBase(".idea/templates");

        HandlerList handlers = new HandlerList();
        handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{resource_handler, context});

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(handlers);

        server.start();
        java.util.logging.Logger.getGlobal().info("Server started");
        server.join();

    }
}
```

Comment: А чей код в вопросе если вы не понимаете как сделать то что вам нужно?

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы страница сайта выводилась по запросу  http://localhost:8080/main, а не по   http://localhost:8080/index.html, находящийся в ".idea/templates"

Comment: Это я понял еще из вопроса, но хотел узнать я у вас совсем не это, а конкретную проблему с которой вы не можете справиться, сейчас очень похоже что вы даже не пытались поискать информацию самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте еще один handler, смотрите [документацию](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/jetty-11/programming-guide/index.html#pg-server-http-handler-use-util-rewrite-handler):

```
RewriteHandler rewriteHandler = new RewriteHandler();
rewriteHandler.addRule(new RewriteRegexRule("/main", "/index.html"));
...
handlers.setHandlers(new Handler[]{rewriteHandler, resource_handler, context});
```

Для этого в проект нужно добавить библиотеку `jetty-rewrite`. Если используете maven, то так:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-rewrite</artifactId>
  <version>11.0.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Спасибо за документацию, теперь сервер держит ещё переписанный хэндлер, но выдаёт ошибку HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /index.html. Reason:

    Not Found